# position in a file stream

Tags: c#, stream

This is probably a silly question. but of the two following ideas, which is conceptually correct when dealing with streams:

1) position is between characters
(pos0)byte0(pos1)byte1(pos2)byte2

2) position is on the character
(pos0/byte0)(pos1/byte1)(pos2/byte2)

thanks

Comment: There is nothing between the bytes. It's an offset and an offset points to a position in a serie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position is before the byte you read. If the position is 0 and your read one byte, you've read the first byte. If you set the position to the stream size, you can't read anything since there is nothing behind - you just could append something to file.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i needed.